# Why won't my regular expressions match the following string?

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I am trying to extract the class abbreviation (Econ 114) and name (Adv Quant Methods) from strings similar to `ECON 114 - 01&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Adv Quant Methods` in python.

I am using the expression `r'(?i)(\w+\s\w+)+\s-\s\w+[&nbsp;]+([\w\s]+\b)'` which works in my regex tester. However, when I run this in scrapy the return array is empty. What am I doing wrong? (code below)

```py
import scrapy;
import re as pythonRe;

#with open('../econ.html', 'r') as f:
    #html_string = f.read()

econ_headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': 'https://pisa.ucsc.edu',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
    'Host': 'pisa.ucsc.edu',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Referer': 'https://pisa.usc.edu/class_search/',
    'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip', 'deflate', 'br'],
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

class ClassesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "classes"


    def start_requests(self):
   
        urls = [
            'https://pisa.usc.edu/class_search/index.php'
            ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, method="POST", headers=econ_headers, body='action=results&binds%5B%3Aterm%5D=2228&binds%5B%3Areg_status%5D=all&binds%5B%3Asubject%5D=ECON&binds%5B%3Acatalog_nbr_op%5D=%3D&binds%5B%3Acatalog_nbr%5D=&binds%5B%3Atitle%5D=&binds%5B%3Ainstr_name_op%5D=%3D&binds%5B%3Ainstructor%5D=&binds%5B%3Age%5D=&binds%5B%3Acrse_units_op%5D=%3D&binds%5B%3Acrse_units_from%5D=&binds%5B%3Acrse_units_to%5D=&binds%5B%3Acrse_units_exact%5D=&binds%5B%3Adays%5D=&binds%5B%3Atimes%5D=&binds%5B%3Aacad_career%5D=&binds%5B%3Aasynch%5D=A&binds%5B%3Ahybrid%5D=H&binds%5B%3Asynch%5D=S&binds%5B%3Aperson%5D=P', callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        def professor_filter(item):
          if (pythonRe.search(r'\w\.', item) or "Staff" in item):
            return True

        #class_regex = pythonRe.compile(r'(?i)(\w+\s\w+)+\s-\s\w+[&nbsp;]+([\w\s]+\b)')
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        classDict = {}
        classes = response.xpath('//a[contains(@id, "class_id")]/text()').re(r'(?i)(\w+\s\w+)+\s-\s\w+[&nbsp;]+([\w\s]+\b)')
        professors = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "col-xs-6 col-sm-3")]/text()').getall()

        professors_filtered = list(filter(professor_filter, professors))

        #for x in range((len(classes))):
          #classDict[classes[x]] = {'professor': professors_filtered[x]}

        print(classes)
        print(len(classes))
        print(professors_filtered)
        print(len(professors_filtered))
        print(professors)
        print(classDict)
        
        filename = f'class-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Comment: `[&nbsp;]` means "one of the characters `&`, `n`, `b`, `s`, `p`, `;`". That probably has something to do with it.

Comment: It would be more specific to match multiple of those exact characters in order but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. My understanding is that my current regex will match any 1+ of those characters.

Comment: Your regex & sample string seem to work here: https://regex101.com/r/nADiHE/1. Which "return array" exactly is empty? Maybe it has a different reason than the regex.

Comment: The classes array is empty when it wasn't before I added the regex. I'm pretty confused, maybe there is something going on with scrapy's custom `.re` method.

Comment: maybe first you should check what you really get in HTML - `response.page`. Server may send different HTML then you expect. i.e it may send Captcha to check if you are human. OR maybe in real HTML there are other chars which you didn't use in your regex.

Comment: `scrapy` has `FormRequest` to send `POST`

Comment: do you really have to use regex? You can `split("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;")` and later `split("-")`. Maybe first get full text from `xpath` and display it to see what you really have in text.

Comment: I think it is wrong idea to search separatelly classes and professors - you filter professors and later you can't match correct professor to correct class. I would rather first search all `div` with row in table, and later in every row search name and professor to create pairs `[class, professor]` - this way you can filter pairs. And if in table there will be class without professor then you catch this problem.

Comment: Yes that's a better format, I was just trying to isolate the problem. I'm going to add more scraped information about each class and was going to use a dictionary with the class names as keys. I'm not sure if there's a better way to isolate professor name so the weird filtering isn't necessary, the professor name text is literally just thrown in before an unrelated `div` closing tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would first get full text for `classes` and display it
then you would see that `scrapy` gives `\xa0` instead of `&nbsp;`

And you have to use `\xa0+` instead of `[&nbsp;]+`

```
classes = response.xpath('//a[contains(@id, "class_id")]/text()').re(r'(?i)(\w+\s\w+)+\s-\s\w+[\xa0]+([\w\s]+\b)')
```

and this gives me:

```
classes: ['ECON 1', 'Intro Microeconomic', 'ECON 1', 'Intro Microeconomic', 'ECON 2', 'Intro Macroeconomic', 'ECON 10A', 'Econ of Accounting', 'ECON 10A', 'Econ of Accounting', 'ECON 11A', 'Math Methd for Econ', 'ECON 11B', 'Math Methds Econ II', 'ECON 100A', 'Intermed Microecon', 'ECON 100A', 'Intermed Microecon', 'ECON 100B', 'Intermed Macroecon', 'ECON 101', 'Managerial Econ', 'ECON 104', 'Numbr Truth', 'ECON 111A', 'Intermed Account I', 'ECON 113', 'Intro Econometrics', 'ECON 113', 'Intro Econometrics', 'ECON 114', 'Adv Quant Methods', 'ECON 117B', 'Tax Factors', 'ECON 125', 'Econ History Of US', 'ECON 126', 'Why Succeed', 'ECON 133', 'Security Markets', 'ECON 136', 'Business Strategy', 'ECON 141', 'Internatl Finance', 'ECON 150', 'Public Finance', 'ECON 161A', 'Marketing', 'ECON 166A', 'Game Theory']
```

---

I think problem is because `response.body` gives original string with HTML but other functions may have to convert this string to `HTML Tree` (like in modules `lxml` or `BeautifulSoup`) and it may automatically convert `html entities` (like `&nbsp;`) to chars.

As I know `scrapy` uses [parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to select elements in HTML.

See Scrapy doc: [Selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code with other changes

- I use FormRequest
- first I search rows in table and later search class and professor in every row separatelly.

```
import scrapy
import re

econ_headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': 'https://pisa.ucsc.edu',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-us',
    'Host': 'pisa.ucsc.edu',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15',
    'Referer': 'https://pisa.usc.edu/class_search/',
    'Accept-Encoding': ['gzip', 'deflate', 'br'],
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

data = {
    'action': 'results',
    'binds[:term]': '2228',
    'binds[:reg_status]': 'all',
    'binds[:subject]': 'ECON',
    'binds[:catalog_nbr_op]': '=',
    'binds[:catalog_nbr]': '',
    'binds[:title]': '',
    'binds[:instr_name_op]': '=',
    'binds[:instructor]': '',
    'binds[:ge]': '',
    'binds[:crse_units_op]': '=',
    'binds[:crse_units_from]': '',
    'binds[:crse_units_to]': '',
    'binds[:crse_units_exact]': '',
    'binds[:days]': '',
    'binds[:times]': '',
    'binds[:acad_career]': '',
    'binds[:asynch]': 'A',
    'binds[:hybrid]': 'H',
    'binds[:synch]': 'S',
    'binds[:person]': 'P',
}

def professor_filter(item):
    return (re.search(r'\w\.', item) or "Staff" in item)

class ClassesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = "classes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://pisa.ucsc.edu/class_search/index.php']
        for url in urls:
            #yield scrapy.Request(url,
            #                     headers=econ_headers,
            #                     body='action=results&binds%5B%3Aterm%5D=2228&binds%5B%3Areg_status%5D=all&binds%5B%3Asubject%5D=ECON&binds%5B%3Acatalog_nbr_op%5D=%3D&binds%5B%3Acatalog_nbr%5D=&binds%5B%3Atitle%5D=&binds%5B%3Ainstr_name_op%5D=%3D&binds%5B%3Ainstructor%5D=&binds%5B%3Age%5D=&binds%5B%3Acrse_units_op%5D=%3D&binds%5B%3Acrse_units_from%5D=&binds%5B%3Acrse_units_to%5D=&binds%5B%3Acrse_units_exact%5D=&binds%5B%3Adays%5D=&binds%5B%3Atimes%5D=&binds%5B%3Aacad_career%5D=&binds%5B%3Aasynch%5D=A&binds%5B%3Ahybrid%5D=H&binds%5B%3Asynch%5D=S&binds%5B%3Aperson%5D=P',
            #                     callback=self.parse)

            yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,
                                 headers=econ_headers,
                                 formdata=data,
                                 callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):

        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]

        all_rows = response.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "rowpanel_")]')

        classDict = {}
        
        for row in all_rows:
            classname = row.xpath('.//h2//a/text()').re(r'(?i)(\w+\s\w+)+\s-\s\w+\xa0+([\w\s]+\b)')
            professor = row.xpath('(.//div[@class="panel-body"]//div)[3]/text()').get().strip()
            print(classname, professor)
            if professor and professor_filter(professor):
                classDict[tuple(classname)] = [professor]
                yield {'class': tuple(classname), 'professor': professor}  # it will write to file csv
            else:
                print('skip:', professor)
        print(classDict)
        
        #filename = f'class-{page}.html'
        #with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        #    f.write(response.body)
        #self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    #'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'FEEDS': {'output.csv': {'format': 'csv'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(ClassesSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: This works but the HTML file that scrapy saved shows `&nbsp;`. Could you tell me what causes the difference?

Comment: I'm not sure why it happens but `response.body` gives original string with HTML but other functions may have to convert this string to `HTML Tree` (like in modules `lxml` or `beautifulsoup`) and it may automatically convert `html entities` like `&nbsp;` to chars.

Comment: I added full working code with other changes - I use `FormRequest` and first search rows in table and later search class and professor in this row. And I put it in my GitHub [furas / python-examples / scraping](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/__scraping__)

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. I've never used scrapy or python before and I was able to scrape all the information I needed for my project.